# In what cases would GCP Dataflow Streaming Job stop with status as Succeeded?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Dataflow streaming job that stops with status as Succeeded, this happens strangely and only for few of jobs. Usually these jobs read from Kafka and write to Kafka.

What are some cases where this is possible? As my understanding is that a streaming job can not technically succeed as it is a streaming job.

Comment: Are you sure your jobs are streaming jobs ? If it read and write to Kafka, normally the job should not finish as succeeded.

Comment: Coincidentally, I created a Dataflow streaming job which ended with 'Succeeded' this week. I had batch source, but forced the pipeline to start as streaming job, via the pipeline options. Eventually, the source was fully read and thus the pipeline finished.

Comment: @MazlumTosun Yes, Hence the question. Btw, this was resolved after I upgraded the beam version to latest.